# What is the mybatis sql variable syntax for literals

Tags: sql, mybatis

I have a bunch of sql in `*Dao.java` files that look something like:

```
select * from table where id = #{id};
```

It works fine if all I want is 1 record where ID is an int.  However, I want to write a statement like this:

```
select * from table where id in (#{idList});
```

How do I change `#{idList}` so that the list (which is passed in as a String of concatenated IDs) will not be wrapped with quotes in the actual sql statement that results?

Right now the resulting sql is something like:

```
select * from table where id in ('1,2,3,4,5');
```

and I'd like it to be

```
select * from table where id in (1,2,3,4,5);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MyBatis uses `${variable}` to support literals. For your case, the sql could be as follows.

```
select * from table where id in (${idList})
```

**But just remember, `${}` CANNOT prevent `sql injection`.** If you can make sure `sql injection` is not possible for your case, it's fine.

An alternative is to use `foreach` to support `in` closure with `MyBatis 3`. Please refer to http://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html#foreach for detail.

For your case, the sql could be:

```
select * from table where id in
<foreach item="item" index="index" collection="list"
    open="(" separator="," close=")">
    #{item}
</foreach>
```

And the parameter type is `List`, but not a string of concatenated IDs.